# hierarchy of implementation for IAuthenticationHanlder

Tags: asp.net-core

I having a hard time following the IAuthenticationHanlder inheritance hierarchy of aspnetcore when

What is confusing is that the hierarchies has multiple sub-branches and the implementations diverge in strange ways, for example

1 - CookieAuthenticationHandler derives from SignInAuthenticationHandler and SignOutAuthenticationHandler (which derive from AuthenticationHandler

2- Surprisingly, JwtBearerHandler derives directly from AuthenticationHandler although I would have expected JWT to also supporting both sign in and sign out

3- To add to the confusion OpenIdConnectHandler doesn't derive from JwtBearerHandler but rather from RemoteAuthenticationHandler although one would think OpenIdConnectHandler is a form of JwtBearerHandler

Any clarifications would be welcome

Comment: _" although I would have expected JWT to also supporting both sign in and sign out"_ - auth cookie usually is set by the server serving the request while JWT usually comes from another source and handled on client side, so personally I would not expect server sign-out functionality with JWT. _"I having a hard time following the IAuthenticationHanlder inheritance hierarchy of aspnetcore"_ - why do you bother at all?

Comment: Thank you @GuruStron, yes indeed it does appear to be a painful exercise to read the source code of aspnetcore, but I was hoping to get better understanding of what is happening under the hood, and understanding some of the magic behind all these nicely named extension methods, and builders